# Ultrasonic Sensor isn't consistent

Tags: sensor

I setup [ultrasonic sensor](http://www.ekt2.com/products/productdetails?ProductId=2ec67a91-978e-4a2f-8524-e672539d9644) on B+, following instructions given in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xACy8l3LsXI). But each time I test I get a different distance for the same object which hasn't moved, seems like it decreases every time i use it.

In my project I rely heavily on those sensors, I bought 5 of them and need them to stay consistent. Should I buy other kind of sensors or change the script or modify the way i setup the sensors?

Comment: What happens if you swap out the sensor for one of the others? This will help us diagnose the problem. Also, please edit your question and include the code you are using, and add a picture of the connections. You also say that the reading varies can you give a specific set of readings. Are you using multiple sensors at once, so that they may interfere with one another?

Comment: Ditto re: If you want someone to make the effort to provide you advice, you should make the effort to provide relevant useful information yourself -- few people are going to bother watching a video and committing various details from it to memory just to help you, so unless someone who has the  same sensor and has had the same problem and knows a solution just happens to stumble in today, this question is *guaranteed* to collect dust.

Comment: Also make sure you are powering them from 5V (with a suitable voltage divider to 3V3 on the echo line).  They will function off 3V3 but the readings will be erratic.

Comment: ill edit it tomorrow to include every detail u want, please wait till then and I'll notify u, if u dont want to watch the video, and i'll try the suggestions tomorrow and update the question then

Comment: For interest the difference between [3V3 and 5V power](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=183386#p183386)

Comment: @Fischer It's unlikely I personally would have an answer to this anyway -- but as a mod here I watch most everything that happens and get to go through our *immense* backlog of unanswered questions...point being if you need help, it is worth putting in a half hour to put together an appropriately detailed (by which I don't mean 1/2 of mindless typing) question -- even (or especially) if it seems like a long shot.  I have to look for help sometimes too, and the harder you try and the more seriously you can present yourself, the better your chances.

Comment: ...If you don't have the time to do it right in the first place, wait until you do.  Saving yourself that 1/2 hour WRT a critical problem in something you've spend dozens or hundreds of hours on otherwise is not worth it if it means the difference between a solution and no solution.  When you need help online, ignore whatever par you perceive there and instead take it as seriously as you do the rest of your work -- because that's what it's part of.  http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html  OTOH hopefully joan's tip about voltage does the trick -- if so leave an answer of your own.